# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: encryption, aes

With an AES key that I retrieve from a Key Vault I'm trying to decrypt a blob file. But I keep getting:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified key is
>   not a valid size for this

I'm trying to reverse engineer a python decrypt situation and this suggests to me that the value I'm retrieving from the key vault is a hex string or at least should be stored as hexstrings in a bytearray.

```
Python:

aes_key= bytes.fromhex(aes_key)
```

So because I get it from my configuration with `var keyStringValue = _configuration.GetValue<string>("the-key-i-want");` I first convert to a bytearray to be able to convert it to hexstring. And then put it in a bytearray again.

```
    //Where I convert my Keyvault keyStringValue to a hexString encoded bytearray
byte[] tempBytes = utf8.GetBytes(keyStringValue);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(tempBytes);
hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "").ToLower();

int NumberChars = hexString.Length;
byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
byte[] pass = bytes;
```

I pass the pass variable to my decrypt function which looks like this:

```
 var crypto = new AesCryptographyService();

 var decryptedData = crypto.Decrypt(postSplitByteArray, pass, iv)
```

And finally my decrypt:

```
public class AesCryptographyService

{      public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using var aes = Aes.Create();


        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;

        using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
        {
            return PerformCryptography(data, decryptor);
        }
    }


 private byte[] PerformCryptography(byte[] data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The hexstring is 128 characters long. And the resultant bytearray 64. Now I know that the array should only be 32 bytes big. But I can't see the point of just cutting my key to size. Nor do I get a properly decrypted result. This bugs me since the python function seems to be doing the same as I am.

```
 cipher = AES.new(aes256_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data).decode('utf-8')
```

PS. I verified with an online converter that the conversion from string to hexstring is going well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not first convert my string into a bytearray and then do a hexstring conversion.

The string in the keyvault was already a "hexstring"

So getting rid of this.

```
byte[] tempBytes = utf8.GetBytes(keyStringValue);
var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(tempBytes);
hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

And from

```
var keyStringValue = _configuration.GetValue<string>("the-key-i-want")
```

pass that to the hexstring conversion

```
  private static byte[] FromHex(string keyStringValue)
        {
            int NumberChars = keyStringValue.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(keyStringValue.Substring(i, 2), 16);

            return bytes;
        }
```

And Bob is your uncle.